# SSL Stripping + HSTS

Tags: sslstrip

What do you think would happen if someone accesses a site that has the HTST mechanism enabled, for the first time? Would SSL Stripping still be possible?

Comment: Does the thread [HSTS bypass with SSLstrip2 + DNS2proxy](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/84767/32746) answers to your question (in particular "*If the client is requesting for the first time the server, it will work anytime*")?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers includes a mechanism named "HSTS preload", which consists of a list of sites which uses HSTS to avoid this "first-access" attack.

- [Chromium](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json)
- [Firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc)

Google made a [website](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/) which can be used to request the insertion of your website in those lists.